# Character ArrayList, Replacing only Characters

Tags: java, arraylist, replace, character

I've created an array list in my program that i'd like to be able to change.  In order to do this I've tried to use `ArrayListName.set(i,'!')`, but the problem is that I want it to only replace characters and NOT spaces.

How can I get it to do that?  Thank you!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args){

    String words = new String("HELLO GOODBYE!");
    ArrayList<Character> sample = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)
        sample.add(words.charAt(i));

    for(int i = 0; i < sample.size(); i++)
        sample.set(i,'!');

}
```

A sample output (I'd like) would be a change from:
HELLO GOODBYE!
to:
!!!!! !!!!!!!!

Comment: oh i'm sorry i forgot to write that out, i'll add it in @Unihedron

Comment: Do want to replace all characters that aren't space? Or do you only want to replace uppercase and lowercase characters? Would HELLO G**DBYE! change to: !!!!! !**!!!!! ?

Comment: I think I'd like to make any character that's not a space have the ability to be replaced @Darwyn

Answer (score 1):

From the Java API for the String class:

In your loop:

```
if (charAt(i) != ' ' //space)) {
 sample.set(i,'!');
}
```

For more info, read the Java API for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: Why not use `charAt(i) != ' '`?

Comment: I just used 32 out of habits

Comment: Oh thank you! But now how can I get it to still have the spaces in between words?

Comment: @user3806226: that's what the above does. Have you tried understanding the code, and running it?

Comment: It keeps the whitespaces.

Comment: I think I was making a typo the first few times i tried it.  I got it to work now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things you could do, probably the simplest to learn would be using an if statement to check for white space.

```
   for(int i = 0; i<sample.size();i++){
       if(!Character.isWhitespace(sample.get(i)) {
           sample.set(i,'!');
       }
   }
```

Comment: Oh thank you! But now how can I get it to still have the spaces in between words?

Comment: @user3806226: that's what the above does. Have you tried understanding the code, and running it?

Comment: yes I tried that, and changed to have the correct number of exclamation points, but what I want is it to change from:
HELLO GOODBYE!   to
!!!!! !!!!!!!!

Comment: And that's what the above does. Print the list after this loop, and you'll see that it contains a space.

Comment: yes, I was making an error. I'm not too familiar with array lists yet.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Better you use REGEX and the String Method replaceALL

```
String helloWorld = "HELLO WORLD!";
String newVal = helloWorld.replaceAll("\\S", "!");
```

This REGEX replace all non whitespace characters.